# pass a binary string from php to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having the following php binary string

```
$buff=chr(1);
$buff.=chr(2);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(6);
$buff.=chr(1);
$buff.=chr(6);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(192);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(1)
```

and i want to pass it to my javascript variable as follow `var buf=<?=$buff?>;` but it displays an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

i tried to make the `chr` conversion in JavaScritp using  `fromCharCode()` CharCodeAt() `toString(2)` but still does get same conversion as php does with `chr` .

What can be the solution to this issue ? what do i put `var buf=<?= here ?>`? to pass the my php string to the javascript code or how can i have an equivalent conversion as`chr` in javascript . 
The solutions i have found so far have been as i stated above but none of them worked !

Help Please

Thanks

Comment: You could encode your buffer as Base64 and decode client-side.

Comment: The main reason you are getting invalid or unexpected token is because you do not open or close the string with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly not enclosing your Javascript in a `script` tag? You want to make sure you put your variable value in quotes.

```
<?php

$buff=chr(1);
$buff.=chr(2);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(6);
$buff.=chr(1);
$buff.=chr(6);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(192);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(1)
?>

<script>
var buf="<?=$buff ?>";
console.log(buf);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your unexpected token is mainly because you end up with this kind of javascript once PHP ran:

```
//Let's say $buff is "i am a binary string"
var buf=<?=$buff?>; //translates to 
var buf=i am a binary string;
```

This is not valid javascript, we should enclose the string inside quotes as we normally do.

```
//Let's say $buff is "i am a binary string"
var buf="<?=$buff?>"; //translates to 
var buf="i am a binary string";
```

This will become a valid string, and should work just like that. If you want to make a bit more certain for your binary to not get replaced by some funky unknown behaviour, you could base64 encode it with PHP and decode it with javascript, but that's unnecessary.

```
var buf = atob("<?= base64_encode($buff);?>");
```